# VS Code behaving strange when trying to import a stylesheet

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio-code, import

I'm trying to import the stylesheet like this `@import"../../../../styles/forms.scss";`

But I get this error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):`
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.`
1 │ @import"../../../styles/variables.scss";
```

(it goes back three times instead of four like in my path)

Then when I go back once more (just to test) `"../../../../../styles/forms.scss"`, VS Code goes back 5 times. I know the path I'm typing is right. I am using Angular if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I imported variables.scss within my forms.scss file and when I called forms.scss one level deeper, it couldn't find variables.scss with the path I specified in forms.scss.

Now I removed variables.scss from forms.scss and added them separately to each file and it works.